# Hapi.js, Bookshelf.js and a real world example

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I've been experimenting with Hapi.js recently and although it's a great framework there doesn't seem to be any real-world examples that are of any use.

One thing missing is the best way to load Models / Collections within Hapi (and node in general to be fair).

Is there any recommended best way of loading these with Hapi?

I'm currently separating all my route logic into plugins and I'm simply creating the Models and Collections within that plugin. I then use `plugin.method('Models.MyModel', Model);` method to make the model available throughout the application. The is fine for a small application but as the app gets bigger I'd like to split thing out more so I can separate routing and storage from the business logic.

Comment: npmjs.org is being rewritten in hapi: https://github.com/npm/newww (don't know it answers your question, but it's a good real-world example)

Answer (score 1):

I've just started to make a Project using Hapi and Boostrap. You can check it here 
https://github.com/codetrash/hapi-project